# Copiar datos tipo texto de excel a word VBA

Tags: vba

Estoy generando una macro que me copie datos de excel a word, pero me marca error, les comporto el codigo que tengo, esperando me puedan ayudar.

```
Sub copiar_word()
Dim wordapp As Object
Dim x, a As Integer
x = 8
Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
With wordapp
    .Visible = True
    .Activate
    .Documents.Add
End With
c = ActiveSheet.Range("a" & x).Value
Do While c <> ""
    ActiveSheet.Range("a" & x).Select
    Selection.Copy
    wordapp.Selection.PasteSpecial link:=True
    If ActiveSheet.Range("a" & x + 1).Value = "" Then
        a = x + 1
        Do While ActiveSheet.Range("a" & a).Select = ""
            a = a + 1
        Loop
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(x, 2), Cells(a, 2)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        wordapp.Selection.PasteSpecial link:=True
        x = x + a
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("b" & x).Select
        Selection.Copy
        wordapp.Selection.PasteSpecial link:=True
        x = x + 1
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Que error te marca?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en la columna tengo el titulo de la información que hay en la columna B, entonces lo que quiero hacer es copiar el titulo y que copie lo que hay en la columba b hasta el otro titulo y error que me muestra es "word cannot obtain the data for the link

Comment: Yo verifique tu código y solo me marca error de desbordamiento, que ya explique abajo. ¿que tipo de formato tiene la celda donde te marca el error?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que cuando la corro me copia las primeras lineas, pero no termina todo el ciclo

Comment: el código se detendrá cuando no encuentre datos en la celda que se itera de la columna A, por que eso le dice tu código que haga.

Te sugiero que para tu otra duda hagas una nueva pregunta, de lo contrario podría ser muy confuso para los otros usuarios que tengan un problema similar.

Answer (score 1):

Si el error que te marca es "desbordamiento", es debido a que tu `Do While`continua indefinidamente.

para resolverlo se tiene que reasignar el valor de tu variable `c` antes de cerrar tu `loop`

```
Sub copiar_word()
Dim wordapp As Object
Dim x, a As Integer
x = 8
Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
With wordapp
    .Visible = True
    .Activate
    .Documents.Add
End With
c = ActiveSheet.Range("a" & x).Value
Do While c <> ""
    ActiveSheet.Range("a" & x).Select
    Selection.Copy
    wordapp.Selection.PasteSpecial link:=True
    If ActiveSheet.Range("a" & x + 1).Value = "" Then
        a = x + 1
        Do While ActiveSheet.Range("a" & a).Select = ""
            a = a + 1
        Loop
        ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(x, 2), Cells(a, 2)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        wordapp.Selection.PasteSpecial link:=True
        x = x + a
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range("b" & x).Select
        Selection.Copy
        wordapp.Selection.PasteSpecial link:=True
        x = x + 1
    End If
    c = ActiveSheet.Range("a" & x).Value
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Arturo, no se si me puedas ayudar con otra duda que tengo, lo que pasa es que en este programita quiero copiar el titulo, que se encuentra en la columna A, y el contenido que esta en la columna B.
Obviamente existen varios columnas de separación entre cada titulo, pero al momento que correr el programa solo me copia el primer titulo con su contenido y el segundo titulo lo copia y pega varias veces sin su contenido, te comparto el programa para que me ayudes a encontrar mi error. Muchas gracias:

Comment: Haber si te entiendo, en la columna A guardas titulos, en la columna B texto, ahora bien quieres que si hay texto en a lo copie a word, si no hay texto copie b.